# How to set priority of ExchangeService's ReponseMessage

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, mailmessage, system.net.mail

I'm using `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService` to find a particular email and Reply All to it.  I know using System.Net.Mail's `MailMessage`, I'm able to set the `Priority` property.  I'm not seeing the equivalent of this using `ExchangeService`?

```
var exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("usr", "pw", "myDomain.com");
exchangeService.TraceEnabled = false;
exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl($"{usr}@myDomain.com", AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

It finds an email:

```
var filter = new SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
var results = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, filter, new ItemView(50));

var interesting = results.Items.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Subject == "interesting");
```

It creates a Reply All email:

```
var response = interesting.CreateReply(true);
response.Body = "I'm important!";
response.Priority = MailPriority.High; // No such property?

response.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Comment: what is var response? `public sealed class ResponseMessage : ResponseObject<EmailMessage>` ? You might have to cast it to an EmailMessage object in order to access the Importance property

Comment: @hellyale Got the error: Cannot convert type `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ReponseMessage` to `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage`.  Tried both using `(cast)` and `as`.

Comment: I've updated my answer and tested it you should be good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing `var response = interesting.CreateReply(true);`

Set the importance of the interesting variable like so 
`interesting.Importance = Importance.Low;` NOTE: If `var interesting` is not an `EmailMessage` cast it first. It might be of type `Item`

When you call `CreateReply()` the importance will carry over into the reply.

I tested this like so

```
var interesting = results.Items.FirstOrDefault();
var orignal = (EmailMessage)interesting; 
orignal.Importance = Importance.Low; orignal.CreateReply(true); 
orignal.Subject = "Low priority"; 
orignal.ToRecipients.Add("myemail@domain.com"); 
orignal.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

The original email was a high priority and the response was a low priority

Comment: `'ReponseMessage' does not contain a definition for 'Importance' and no extension method....`  And I cannot cast, as noted in comment up above.